# In Excel, How do I sum a 2 different rows then divide when different criteria is met?

Tags: excel, formulas

What I am trying to do, and I have no idea how to approach this is....

Sum what is in column R when what is in column C is < 0, and add that to the sum of what is in column T when what is in column C is >= 0.

Then divided that sum of the two above by the sum of columns R + V when C <0, and columns T + X when C >= 0

Comment: Edit your question to provide sample data and expected results.  Also include any formulas you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=(SUMIF(C:C,"<0",R:R)+SUMIF(C:C,">=0",T:T))/(SUMIF(C:C,"<0",R:R)+SUMIF(C:C,"<0",V:V)+SUMIF(C:C,">=0",T:T)+SUMIF(C:C,">=0",X:X))
```